# Maven: Deploying from an existing tag?

Tags: maven, mercurial, maven-3

I'm trying to deploy the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of an artifact. I invoked `release:prepare release:perform` to deploy the 32-bit version but when I repeat the same command to deploy the 64-bit version (using the 64-bit profile) I get:

```
Checking in modified POMs...
EXECUTING: cmd.exe /X /C "hg commit --message "[maven-release-plugin] prepare release release-1.46.1" C:\Users\Gili\Documents\boost-maven-project\pom.xml C:\Users\Gili\Documents\boost-maven-project\boost-maven-plugin\pom.xml C:\Users\Gili\Documents\boost-maven-project\boost-compiler\pom.xml C:\Users\Gili\Documents\boost-maven-project\boost-api\pom.xml C:\Users\Gili\Documents\boost-maven-project\boost-date-time\pom.xml C:\Users\Gili\Documents\boost-maven-project\boost-filesystem\pom.xml C:\Users\Gili\Documents\boost-maven-project\boost-graph\pom.xml C:\Users\Gili\Documents\boost-maven-project\boost-iostreams\pom.xml C:\Users\Gili\Documents\boost-maven-project\boost-math\pom.xml C:\Users\Gili\Documents\boost-maven-project\boost-program-options\pom.xml C:\Users\Gili\Documents\boost-maven-project\boost-random\pom.xml C:\Users\Gili\Documents\boost-maven-project\boost-regex\pom.xml C:\Users\Gili\Documents\boost-maven-project\boost-serialization\pom.xml C:\Users\Gili\Documents\boost-maven-project\boost-signals\pom.xml C:\Users\Gili\Documents\boost-maven-project\boost-system\pom.xml C:\Users\Gili\Documents\boost-maven-project\boost-test\pom.xml C:\Users\Gili\Documents\boost-maven-project\boost-thread\pom.xml C:\Users\Gili\Documents\boost-maven-project\boost-wave\pom.xml"
[ERROR]
EXECUTION FAILED
  Execution of cmd : commit failed with exit code: 1.
  Working directory was: 
    C:\Users\Gili\Documents\boost-maven-project
  Your Hg installation seems to be valid and complete.
    Hg version: 1.8.2 (OK)

EXECUTING: cmd.exe /X /C "hg push https://boost-maven-project.googlecode.com/hg/"
Tagging release with the label release-1.46.1...
EXECUTING: cmd.exe /X /C "hg tag --message "[maven-release-plugin]  copy for tag release-1.46.1" release-1.46.1"
[ERROR]
EXECUTION FAILED
  Execution of cmd : tag failed with exit code: -1.
  Working directory was: 
    c:\users\gili\documents\boost-maven-project
  Your Hg installation seems to be valid and complete.
    Hg version: 1.8.2 (OK)
```

If I invoke `release:perform` alone, I get:

```
[ERROR]Cannot perform release - the preparation step was stopped mid-way. Please re-run release:prepare to continue, or perform the release from an SCM tag.
```

How can I `release:perform` from an existing SCM tag? I tried adding `-Dtag=foo` but got the same error message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run release:perform from a given Git tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18943347/how-to-run-releaseperform-from-a-given-git-tag)

Comment: @Joe, this is not a duplicate because each provider (e.g. Git, Mercurial) handles this differently. I've added a tag to clarify this question is Mercurial-specific.

Comment: I believe Git and Mercurial are close enough in this case; does the `scm.tag`/`scm.url` solution proposed in the other question not work for Mercurial?

Comment: @Joe I believe that'll work too but creating files from inside Maven is harder than passing command-line options (as I have done in the answer below).

Comment: You say in your answer 'there is no way to specify a tag'. That's exactly the problem that the other answer works around, although it is less convenient than passing command-line arguments.

Comment: @Joe good point. I'll link to it from my answer. Thanks for the head's up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question. You can use:

```
mvn release:perform -DconnectionUrl=scm:hg:https://boost-maven-project.googlecode.com/hg/
```

but there is no way to specify a tag for Mercurial repositories. I filed this bug report: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-969

**UPDATE**: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/18943705/14731 you should be able to set the tag by creating `release.properties`, but I have not tested this.