# How to run release:perform from a given Git tag?

Tags: git, maven, maven-release-plugin

Due to issues with a Nexus staging repository, I need to re-run `mvn release:perform`, ideally without creating a new Git tag but reusing the one created by the first run.

I tried

```
mvn release:perform
-DconnectionUrl=scm:git:git@github.com:ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.exam2.git 
-Dtag=exam-reactor-3.3.0
```

and

```
mvn release:perform
-DconnectionUrl=scm:git:git@github.com:ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.exam2.git 
-Dscm.tag=exam-reactor-3.3.0
```

but in both cases, the clone fails because the tag/branch parameter is not forwarded to Git:

```
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.4:perform (default-cli) @ exam-reactor ---
[INFO] Checking out the project to perform the release ...
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/hwellmann/work/org.ops4j.pax.exam2/target && git clone --branch git@github.com:ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.exam2.git /home/hwellmann/work/org.ops4j.pax.exam2/target/checkout
```

Note: `release.properties` and other stuff created by `mvn release:prepare` is no longer available.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This issue is filed as [SCM-729](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SCM-729), and currently unresolved. In the meantime, you might consider a workaround.

The simplest is to forget about `maven-release-plugin`; clone, check out that tag and then run `mvn deploy`.

Alternatively, you can use `release:perform` with a manually edited `release.properties` file. Set `scm.tag` and `scm.url` and then run `release:perform`.

Comment: Ok, I'll watch the JIRA issue... `mvn deploy` does not sign artifacts or produce Javadoc. And as I said, `release.properties` is gone, so I can't tweak it.

Comment: Don't tweak it: create a new file with just those two properties set.